# overwrite some data in a python file

Tags: python, file, overwrite

I was hoping someone could help me, I am currently trying to add some data into a text file, however the way I am doing it isnt giving me what I want. I Have a file with 20+ lines in it with text and want to overwrite the first 30 characters of the file with 30 new characters. The code I have deletes all the content and adds the 30 characters only. Please help :)

```
file=open("text.txt", "w")
```

is there something wrong with this to why its reoving all of the original data too instead of simply overwriting over it?

Comment: RTEM.............

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation of [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open): "`"w"` open for writing, truncating the file first".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to read the whole file into a single string, create a new string with first 30 characters replaced and rewrite the whole file. This can be done like this:

```
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

new_thirty_characters = '<put your data here>'

new_data = new_thirty_characters + data[30:]

with open("text.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(new_data)
```

Ideally, you have to check that file contains more than 30 characters after it's read. Also, do not use **file** and other reserved names as variable names.

Comment: thats a really good way to get around that thank you I will try it